# How to revert a change I made

Tags: git

This might be a dumb question but I rather be safe then messing everything up.

I made two bad commits...I deleted a folder in one commit. In the next commit, I recreated the folder. After I made those commits, my teammates have made commits to the repo, but their commits are independent of my commits. (I have my own folder and I made changes to it).

How can I undo my two commits without affecting the commits made by my teammates?

Lets say the commit hashes are AAA111 for the first commit and BBB222 for the second commit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just revert the commits:

```
$ git revert BBB222 AAA111
```

Comment: You know that `git revert` does NOT undo commits. It creates new commits that undo the stuff that has been done. As OP wrote in his question, BBB222 is the commit `git revert` would create if you called `git revert AAA111`. So reverting them both creates two you commits you don't want.

Comment: @Oznerol256 it does add two commits to the tree, but since the changes are pushed, there is no other way! An interactive rebase that would leave those two commits out is out of the question since since it would change the history and a force push would have been needed. And force pushing on a public repo is probably the worst thing you can do on a repo. Long story short, if you push wrong commits, too bad, you can NOT remove them from history.

Comment: @xlembouras Of course there is no other way. However, commit BBB222 does already revert commit AAA111 (as of OP's statement). Therefore, you don't need to create additional commits to revert anything. And even if BBB222 didn't revert the changes of AAA111, you would still create one reverting commit by using `git revert AAA111 BBB222` (as @michas wrote) instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

If your commits are pushed, you can run `git revert` on each of the commits and undo them.  Or when you are pulling in the changes, you will end up with a merge conflict and the changes will be resolved.

If your changes are only on your local branch, you can `git reset --hard <sha of commit before your commits>`  WARNING: This will delete all your changes.  This will make it so that you commits did not happen.

If your changes are only on your local branch and you have other commits that you want to keep, you can do `git rebase -i <sha of commit before your changes>`, this will bring up an editor listing all the commits that you have.  Delete the two commits that you no longer want, save the file.  This will remove the commits from your history and save the other commits that you have.

Answer (score 1):

If your commits are either not yet pushed or only pushed to a private branch (i.e. no one else is working on that branch) you can use `git rebase -i AAA111^` and delete those commits. In this case your bad commits did never happen. :)

If you already pushed your commits you cannot simply remove those commits. You have to add new commits to undo the changes made by the original commits. Use `git revert AAA111 BBB222` for that.

Comment: OP wrote that BBB222 recreates the folder of AAA111, calling `git revert AAA111 BBB222` will not do anything apart from creating an empty commit.

Comment: If BBB222 already reverts AAA111, then indeed nothing is left to do. In this case the only meaningful interpretation of the question is: "How to remove already pushed commits from history" and the answer is: don't do it.